# ChartJS not showing the title

Tags: chart.js, node-red

The ChartJS is not showing any title. I added the title in option and then plugin, Ieven tried to add some margin because mabe it was hidden by the layout but nothing works. I use node-red to launch the graphic dashboard. I added some CSS to the dashboard but nothing linked directly to the title. Any idea ?

```
<script>


var textcolor = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--nr-dashboard-widgetTextColor');
var gridcolor = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--nr-dashboard-groupBorderColor');
var linecolors = ['#009900','#889900','#755800']

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',
    options: {
        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Difference between temp ext and temp in',
                color:"#000000"
            }
        },

        scales: {
            yAxes: [
                {
                    gridLines :{color:"#ffffff"},
                    id: 'left-y-axis',
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'left',
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: linecolors[0]
                    }
                },
                {
                    gridLines :{zeroLineColor:"#ffffff",color:"#000000",lineWidth:0.1},
                    id: 'right-y-axis',
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'right',
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor:linecolors[1]
                    }
                }
            ],
            xAxes: [
                {
                    gridLines :{zeroLineColor:"#000000",color:"#000000",lineWidth:0.1},
                    type: 'time',
                    distribution: 'series',
                    ticks: {
                        color:'#000000'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        
    },
    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: [],
        
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'First',
         
                backgroundColor: linecolors[0],
                borderColor: linecolors[0],
                data: {{{payload.first}}},
                yAxisID: 'left-y-axis',
                steppedLine: false,
                fill: false,
                borderWidth: 3,
                radius:0,
            
                
            },
            {
                label: 'Second',
             
                backgroundColor: linecolors[1],
                borderColor: linecolors[1],
                data: {{{payload.second}}},
                yAxisID: 'left-y-axis',
                steppedLine: false,
                fill: false,
                borderWidth: 3,
                radius:0,
            
              
            },
            {
                label: 'Third',
         
                backgroundColor: linecolors[2],
                borderColor: linecolors[2],
                data: {{{payload.third}}},
                yAxisID: 'right-y-axis',
                steppedLine: false,
                fill: false,
                borderWidth: 3,
                radius:0,
         
              
            }
        ]
    },
    
    
});


</script>
```

[image]

Comment: If you use the browser development tools to inspect the page, is the title actually present in the page?

Comment: Yes, it is ! In the script tag, my title is there.

Comment: When it works the title is in a <p> tag. So i would say that no it's not recognising the title.

Comment: No, not inside the script tag, I'm asking if it is in the rendered output.

Comment: So then no, not in the rendered output. I tried to add a legend the same way as my title, it does not work neither. Nothing is displayed except the graph itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the title in the root of the options, not in the plugins namespace:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Title text'
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works. I still don't understand why the official doc tell us to put in the pluggin namespace... Anyway

Comment: Because the official docs are for the latest version (3.8.0 at the moment) while you are using V2, between major update from V2 to V3 there have been some breaking changes from which this is one. If you check the V2 docs you can see it needs to be placed in options.title: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/configuration/title.html